# Populating Array with Click Handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having an issue populating state with choices from an array

So I have an array of options which all generate a button -- which, when clicked, have a clickHandler that should populate the state value with each option clicked.

Issue is, it works but skips the first click, meaning I have to click 6 times to register 5 options

```
const options = [
  "tech", "culture",
  "sex", "sports",
  "opinion", "business",
  "food", "health",
  "space"
];

const clickHandler = (option, e , index) => {
  if(userOptions.length < 5) {
      setUserOptions(prevState => prevState.concat(option));
      console.log(userOptions);
  }
}

const buttonList = options.map((element,index) => {
  return (
      <button 
          key={element} 
          disabled={userOptions.includes(element)}
          className={`btn-main ${element}`}
          onClick={(e) => {
            // returns two handleClick methods
            clickHandler(element)
            colorChange(e.target)
          }}
      >
          {element} 
      </button>
  )
})
```

Using array.concat skips the first click entry...is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Code samples should provide the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. Yours calls `colorChange` and sets a state variable `userOptions` but they are not shown, so this example is incomplete.

Comment: Where is `userOptions`?

Comment: its in the App.js file

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be right.

Your `console.log` just right after your `setUserOptions` should be the problem, as the `setState` isn't syncronous the state could be still the same

Try to log the state every render to see the result